# Erro ao criar nó filho, lista generalizada

Tags: c, if

O erro se encontra no `else` do método `criarFilho`, consegui localizá-lo porém não encontro solução para o mesmo.

O *debug* do Dev-C++ não aponta nada.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    //  #include "decisor.h"


    typedef struct node {
        int categoria;
        int atributoOuDecisao;
        struct node *prox;
        struct node *lista;
    } No;

    No *criaArvore(void){

    No *inicio = (No*)malloc(sizeof(No));                       //Aloca memória para filho.
        inicio->atributoOuDecisao = 0;
        inicio->categoria = 99;
        inicio->lista = NULL;                                       //Inicializa Variaveis
        inicio->prox = NULL;
        return inicio;                                              //Retorna Raiz
    }

    No *criaFilho (No *pai, int atributoDoPai, int categoriaDoFilho, int atributoOuDecisao){

        No *p1 = (No*)malloc(sizeof(No));                           //Cria Nó Filho
        p1->atributoOuDecisao = atributoOuDecisao;
        p1->categoria = categoriaDoFilho;
        p1->lista = NULL;
        p1->prox = NULL;
        if (pai->lista = NULL) {                                    //Testa se sublista é vazia, se sim então inicializa sublista com Filho.
            pai->lista = p1;
        }
        else {                                                      //Se pai possui sublista, percorre sublista até o fim com auxiliar e posiciona Filho na ultima posição.
            No *aux;                                            
            aux = pai->lista;
            while (aux->prox != NULL){
                aux = aux->prox;
            }
            aux->prox = p1;
        }
        return p1;                                                  //Retorna      ponteiro para nó Filho
    }


    int main () {
        No *aux, *aux2, *arv;
        int *v;
        arv=criaArvore();
        aux=criaFilho(arv, 1, 1, 3);
        criaFilho(aux, 3, 0, 1);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou um `=` no `if`. Você atribuiu um valor ao invés de comparar. Note que eu melhorei alguns aspectos do código, como eu já havia feito antes. Em C não existem métodos, existem funções. Também aconselho usar outro compilador/IDE. Esse tem problemas e não ajuda achar erros simples como esse. Tem coisa mais moderna.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int categoria;
    int atributoOuDecisao;
    struct node *prox;
    struct node *lista;
} No;

No *criaArvore(void) {
    No *inicio = malloc(sizeof(No));
    inicio->atributoOuDecisao = 0;
    inicio->categoria = 99;
    inicio->lista = NULL;
    inicio->prox = NULL;
    return inicio;
}

No *criaFilho(No *pai, int atributoDoPai, int categoriaDoFilho, int atributoOuDecisao) {
    No *p1 = malloc(sizeof(No));
    p1->atributoOuDecisao = atributoOuDecisao;
    p1->categoria = categoriaDoFilho;
    p1->lista = NULL;
    p1->prox = NULL;
    if (pai->lista == NULL) { // <================== erro aqui
        pai->lista = p1;
    } else {
        No *aux = pai->lista;
        while (aux->prox != NULL) {
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
        pai->prox = p1;
    }
    return p1;
}

int main() {
    No *arv = criaArvore();
    No *aux = criaFilho(arv, 1, 1, 3);
    criaFilho(aux, 3, 0, 1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/B4aeWv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/opvswriw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/StructPointer2.c).

Comment: Novamente, muito obrigado. Recomenda alguma IDE em especial?

Comment: @MarcosPinheiroMoura novamente leia o [tour] para entender o funcionamento do site. Visual Studio é o mais usado em Windows. Se preferir usar o GCC dá no VS também, mas não é comum, aí tem muita opção. Tem quem goste de Code::Blocks, outros preferem outras coisas. Tem muita oferta de coisa boa. Ou seja, basicamente esse é o único ruim. Eu não consigo entender porque tanta gente escolhe usar um software com problemas, que se procurar nem mostra fácil

Comment: @MarcosPinheiroMoura você pode aceitar na outra também.